# How to redirect domain.com to domain.com/blog/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my blog from http://designskew.com to http://designskew.com/blog/.

I searched a lot of .htaccess redirection methods, but nothing worked. the designskew.com redirects always to google. Please help.

Comment: It does redirect currently, though.

Answer (score 0):

it is redirecting as I can see it

Comment: Really, I mean I am trying this from couple of hours but its not redirecting here.

Comment: may be due to cache on your browser.